# string 'xyz' marked untranslatable but exists in locale 'ja'

Tags: android, xml, localization, translation

[image]I am developing an app in android, I have various strings in my strings.xml file. I want to localize strings thus supporting multiple languages.

The problem is I get following error:
warning: string 'enthu' marked untranslatable but exists in locale 'ja' in my strings.xml file on this line:

```
<string name="enthu" translatable="false">Enthusiasm</string>
```

If I change `translatable` to true, error goes, but I have made it false for the required reason.

I have tried following things:

1. Ignore All Lint checking.
2. Added following in my strings.xml

xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      tools:ignore="MissingTranslation"

3. Clean build various times, restarted eclipse.
4. Specifically ignored missing Translation in lint checking and then ran lint for errors.

But every time I failed.
I am using Ubuntu 32Bit, ADT 23.04.14.

This error looks very unusual to me, as I am also ignoring lint warnings.
Kindly help. I am not able to build my src.

Comment: `If I change translatable to true, error goes, but I have made it false for the required reason.`  Not clear. Do you want it translated or not? if not, remove it from the Japanese strings file.

Comment: The fact is I dont want the lint error, I wanna get it translated or not is secondary question. I m little surprised y on earth even after ignoring all for lint error checking, why m i getting this error.

Comment: Lint is configurable. You can decide which warnings to hide or show and each with which criticity level.

Comment: @DerGolem, yes dear I have already stated that I have configured lint to ignore all , but I am still getting this as error.

Comment: Why downward point, its a genuine problem and i m not getting a solution???